# cannot register my app to MFP remove server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am having an issue deploying my app to a remote server. This is the error I get when trying run the cli add command:

mfpdev server add myqaserver --url https://mbmfp.mycompany.com --login admin --password aaaa --setdefault

*Error: URL 'https://mbmfp.mycompany.com' is not valid. The URL must have the following format 'protocol://host:port'. Run 'mfpdev help server add' for more information.*

My hostname name https://mbmfp.mycompany.com contains the port. So adding the port again will cause an issue

Initially, I tried the register command and was prompt to used the add command

mfpdev app register https://mbmfp.mycompany.com mfp

How do I fix this issue?

INFO
IBM MFP version 8.0.0-2016121916

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're executing the commands correctly...

Here's an example:

```
mfpdev server add

? Enter the name of the new server definition: mydevserver
? Enter the fully qualified URL of this server: http://mydevserver.example.com:9080
? Enter the MobileFirst Server administrator login ID: admin
? Enter the MobileFirst Server administrator password: admin
? Save the admin password for this server?: Yes
? Enter the context root of the MobileFirst administration services: mfpadmin
? Enter the MobileFirst Server connection timeout in seconds: 30
Verifying server configuration...
The following runtimes are currently installed on this server: mfp
Server profile 'mydevserver' added successfully.
```

Then, navigate to the root folder of the application and:

```
mfpdev app register mydevserver
```

Learn more here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#add-a-new-server-instance

Comment: Thanks Idan,
 The issue I have is on the second step 
'Enter the fully qualified URL of this server: http://mydevserver.example.com:9080' . 

In my case the port number is embedded in my hostname ' https://mbmfp.mycompany.com'

so,I get a format error

Comment: There's no such thing as "embedded". Specify it whatever it is. 8080, 9080, 10080, whatever...